# Slide, Direction: left not working?

Tags: jquery

does anyone have any idea why this function is not working in Jquery?

```
$('.left').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
```

I am trying to create a button that expands a container and shows a div when clicked.
http://jsfiddle.net/pufamuf/wXyDq/14/
Thanks a lot everyone! :)

Comment: Google Chrome, and I tried it with Firefox 6 yesterday.

Comment: The yellow part that extends is the container getting larger. However, the left div does not slide out.

Comment: are you trying to show the yellow or have the red slide and reveal the green?  if you look at the docs on the .show() command it's not what you want - http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, the easing effect you are using is only available in JQuery UI, or as a separate download, so you need to add a reference to that as well. Then the animation works.

**EDIT:** Looks like that's the problem:

"The only easing implementations in the jQuery library are the default, called swing, and one that progresses at a constant pace, called linear. More easing functions are available with the use of plug-ins, most notably the jQuery UI suite." http://api.jquery.com/animate/

HTH.

Comment: Thanks Tieson, the problem was with the Jquery UI not being implemented. Thanks again :)!

Comment: @pufAmuf Please don't forget to mark this as the answer if you feel it is so.

Comment: Sorry Tieson, I had to leave and I wasn't allowed to accept it until some time has passed :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you have got the syntax wrong for show function. You should probably use

```
$('.left').show();
```

It cannot be used with "slide", like the way you tried. Read the manual.

http://api.jquery.com/show/